# Express/Node issue with routing paths for static files in Jade templates

Tags: node.js, express, pug

I have a Node/Express app with a Jade template that imports a few static files. The salient lines of my jade template look like this:

layout.jade:

```
head
  link(rel="stylesheet" href="/css/main.css)
  script(src="/vendor/jquery.js")

block body
  h1 Hello world.
```

mypage.jade:

```
extend layout

block body append
  p Here another line.
```

In express, I'm routing my views like this:

```
app.get('/', function(req,res) {
    res.render('index')
}

app.get('/mypage/', function(req,res) {
    res.render('mypage')
}
```

The html for mypage.html now has my css and javascript paths as:

```
/mypage/css/main.css
/mypage/vendor/jquery.js
```

How can I get express/Jade to import the static files in my header correctly, ie. without prefixing the route to the path?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you didn't change anything, I believe you still have

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
```

so if you save files like

```
/public/css/main.css
```

It works as you expected

or in the case you want to use `/mypage/css/`, save css or any other static files for mypage in

```
/public/mypage/css/main.css
```

and call it as

```
link(href="/maypage/css/style.css", rel="stylesheet")
```

static file's root is always 'public' so you need the path from it such as `/mypage/css/` even if it's a jade template for `/mypage/`

Comment: Thanks for the help. When I follow your instructions, I use `/public/vendor/stylesheets` in my jade template, but this ends up pointing to `/mypage/public/vendor/stylesheets`

Comment: Thanks, I was missing the leading slash.

Comment: I have `express.static..` line, it works fine on desktop, but on mobile devices I'm having problem only with my logo, which is in `images/logo.png`. When link to my page is changed to `www.weedu.tech/users` browser tries to load logo in `/users/images/logo.png`. Even on mobile it shows logo in first 2-3 seconds and then swaps to the link to `/users/images/logo.png`.